# Is it safe to add CloudFlare nameservers to a VPS?

Tags: ssh, networking, dns, vps

I have an **Ubuntu 22.04 VPS** with public IP and I access the VPS with SSH only, I didn't install a GUI like *xrdp* or *VNC*, I intend to add the CloudFlare nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` and maybe this is what it looks like:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Is it safe if I do this? Or will I lose my SSH access to this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> nameserver 1.1.1.1
> nameserver 127.0.0.53
> ```

> Will I lose my SSH access to this server?

Changing name servers will not break established SSH connections.

New SSH connections will only be impacted if you both rely on reverse DNS records for access controls (which normally one doesn't, but which is allowed with for example the [`from=` option](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#from=_pattern-list_) in `˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` ) AND you make an breaking change, by for example making a typo.

Soo make the change, keep your current session open and log in with a new session after making the change.

> Is it safe if I do this?

Safe? Yes.

The best way? Probably not.

The entry `nameserver 127.0.0.53` suggests that (by default) your system currently uses the systemd resolver [`systemd-resolved`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-resolved.service.html).

You can check and confirm that with `resolvectl status`

If you want to manage and change which (public) resolvers systemd-resolved uses for your system, change the [`resolved.conf` and/or the drop-in `./resolved.conf.d/*.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html) configuration file(s) rather than `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Unlike the traditional resolver behaviour you get by adding a nameserver entry to  [`/etc/resolv.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) staying with the systemd-resolved supports things like [`DNS over TLS`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html#DNSOverTLS=) natively which might be one of the reasons you want to use [CloudFlare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/encryption/dns-over-tls/) and their  [1.1.1.1](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) public resolver in the first place.

---

An example `resolved.conf`  that uses TLS, the CloudFlare public resolvers as preferred  and Google's as back-up :

```
# /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
Domains=~.
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

After restarting  the relevant service (IIRC `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`) you should probably see `resolvectl status` return

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes
      DNSSEC setting: yes
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      1.0.0.1
Fallback DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Answer (score 0):

If DNS lookups are currently broken on that VPS (else you're not really changing anything) *and* you're on a connection with a weird (I'm not even sure what kind of weirdness would be needed, but it's far beyond anything remotely ordinary) IP/reverse DNS setup, I won't rule out that you could get a problem, but it's two very unlikely things that both have to be true.

And I would think the way around it is just to make a new connection after making the edit but before closing the connection you used to make the edit (that won't be affected).